# How to randomly generate user ID without login AWS

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Users can use my app without a login. But they get more features if they create an account, like saving a product.

I'm working through this AWS doc: [Integrate Your Existing NoSQL Table - AWS Mobile Hub Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-nosql-integrate-an-existing-table.html)

But it doesn't appear to have any details about allowing permission for users that don't have a login. I would need to randomly generate an ID when a user first opens the app and still create a user with it.

I've setup a database that has a list of products. That I plan to use the ObjectMapper API to query the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS has a service called [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).
Amazon Cognito has two parts, Cognito user pools and Cognito Federated Identity.

[Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) manages user creation, the storage of credentials, the allocation of groups etc.

[Cognito Federated Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html), converts an authenticated user into AWS IAM credentials.
Cognito Federated Identity can use Cognito [User Pools to authenticate, or Facebook, Amazon, Google, Apple, SAML or OpenID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html).

Cognito Federated Identity allows both Authenticate and Unauthenticated users.
You can switch from [Unauthenticated users to Authenticated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/switching-identities.html) users.

You can use Cognito Federated Indentity to get a user ID by calling [GetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html).
The Logins parameter is optional. GetId will return a unique user Guid each time. You can then store that Guid Locally to track your user, and later if the User decides to signup, you can [link that guid to an authenticated user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/switching-identities.html). The link has iOS code examples.

AWS Mobile Hub (now Amplify) uses Cognito in the background, you can see the process flow [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/User-Sign-in.html).

Comment: Thank you, this has cleared things up. I'm using Amplify and made the correct pools. I'm currently now linking some of the functions up to some buttons to test it.